# Auto add a timestamp depending on value from another column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In table I have:

1. ID
2. DATE_1  (current timestamp)
3. DATE_2

**So, what I need...**

Column "date_2" value should be automatically filled (if that is possible?) with exactly 6-month difference from date_1 (which is a current timestamp that is auto inserted).

Example, if date_1 is 1.01.2018, date_2 should automatically have a value 01.07.2018.

Comment: Which MySQL version do you use?

Comment: MariaDB , 4.7.7

Comment: 4.7.7? Are you sure? Run `SELECT version()`.

Comment: 10.1.30-MariaDB
, sorry...in first post I wrote phpmyadmin version

Comment: Wait.. Do you realy mean "another row"? Or should it be "another column"?

Comment: "another column", you have done a good job, sir :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generated (virtual) column:

```
create table mytable (
    ID int,
    DATE_1 timestamp default now(),
    DATE_2 timestamp as (DATE_1 + interval 6 month),
   primary key (ID)
);
```

Read more about generated columns here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/

Comment: big thanx , Paul